# Is a solution of the form $f(x) = g(y)$ implicit?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, functional-equations, implicit-function

Given a solution of a variable separable equation, say the solution can't be expressed in the form $y = f(x)$ (given $y$ is the dependent variable) and is expressed as $f(x) = g(y)$. Then is it an implicit solution or an explicit solution?

Comment: Implicit solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have made a mistake in the notation; it should be $f(y)=g(x)$ where $f\not=g$.
Still an implicit solution because you cannot compute $y$ in terms of $x$ only.

If you write $f(y)=f(x)$, then we may be able to express $y$ in terms of $x$. For example, if $f$ has an inverse, then taking the inverse function of both sides yields $y=x$.

However, if $f$ has no inverse, the solution is generally implicit. For example, the following has an explicit solution:

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= ax^2+bx+c\\
f(y)=f(x)\implies y&=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2 +4a(ax^2+bx)}}{2a}.
\end{align}$$

Similarly, we can write explicit solutions for cases where $f(x)$ is a polynomial of order 3 or 4, but not order 5 or more. So in general, the solution is implicit.

Comment: $y = x$ is always a solution of $f(y) = f(x)$.  It may not be the only solution, though.

Comment: If $f$ has an inverse, $y=x$ is the only solution because $f^{-1}(f(y)) = f^{-1}(f(x))\implies y = x$.

Comment: The solutions for $y^n = x^n$ are $y = \omega x$ where $\omega$ is an $n$'th root of unity.  The solutions that are real when $x$ is real are $y = x$ and (if $n$ is even) $-x$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, thanks for your correction. I will correct the example.